# different style sheet for just one page template

Tags: functions, customization, page-template, wp-enqueue-style, css

I've been using site/page builders for so long in WP that I'm OOTL with the current setup of templates, stylesheets and functions in the newer WP builds.

I've got an older theme that I need to make a unique page for and am struggling to understand how to use a specific stylesheet for this page template.
If the page template is referral.php and I've added the header and footer into the template (so that I can use unique elements compared to the main site), I can see that the header brings in the sytlesheet using `<?php wp_head(); ?>`.

**What's the best way for this page to use the majority of the parent and child theme styles, but process my specific unique styles for this page ONLY?**

Is it to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>/referral-style.css">` or is it to create a functions file in the child theme directory and use something like:

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<?php
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    if( is_page( 'referral' ) ) {   // Only add this style onto the Blog page.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'referral-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    }
    if ( is_child_theme() ) {
        // load parent stylesheet first if this is a child theme
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-stylesheet', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', false );
    }
    // load active theme stylesheet in both cases
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri(), false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way is to use `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );` within your child theme `functions.php` file or directly in your `referral.php` template page.  Either way, it's by using `add_action` and not by echoing into the `<link>` tag.

Registering your style is also a recommended practice.  The one benefit I would see in your case is that you could register all your styles in your `functions.php` with for each file their dependencies, then you would have to enqueue only one handle in your referral page and WP would load all other files registered as dependencies of your `referral-style.css`.

For instance, in `functions.php`

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
  wp_register_style( 'referral-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'path/to/your/css-file', array( 'theme-stylesheet' ) );
  wp_register_style( 'theme-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  // load active theme stylesheet in all cases
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-stylesheet' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```

and in `referral.php`

```
function my_referral_enqueue_style() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'referral-style' ); // will load theme-stylesheet automatically

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_referral_enqueue_style' );
```

of course you can omit this in `referral.php` and still add a conditional in your `functions.php`

```
if( is_page( 'referral' ) ) {   

  wp_enqueue_style( 'referral-style' );

}
```

But I wanted to show you both ways

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use often some scripts or styles, it's better to register them before `enqueue`. It's kind of informing WordPress that "Please register those scripts and style, I'm gonna need them later."-

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<?php
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'referral-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_register_style( 'parent-stylesheet', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', false  );
    if( is_page( 'referral' ) ) {   // Only add this style onto the Blog page.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'referral-style' );
    }
    if ( is_child_theme() ) {
        // load parent stylesheet first if this is a child theme
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-stylesheet' );
    }
    // load active theme stylesheet in both cases
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri(), false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```